# Microsoft Word Save As Macro Returning Corrupt File

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document which I am using as a template for other projects. The file is saved as an .docx and includes a Macro to save the document with a file name dependent on content control box titled "STATE". I would prefer the macro save the document without the macro included. When I run the macro, the document saves to the correct file location however when opened I get an error that reads:

> We're Sorry. We can't open FILE LOCATION because we found a problem with its contents. No error details available.

I assume there is an error somewhere in my code. I am using Word 2013. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Sub Silent_save_to_DOC()

Dim strText As String, strDate As String, strDrop As String

strText = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("STATE")(1).Range.Text

Dim strFilename As String
strFilename = "C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\Quote - " & strText & ".docx"
ThisDocument.SaveAs strFilename

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that a *.docx file may not contain macros, only *.docm files may contain macros. Your code is forcing Word to save the document with macros and an incompatible file extension. As a security measure Word will not open a *.docx file that contains macros - as the message is informing you.

Use a true template file - *.dotm - to create your documents. The template can contain the macros, which will *not* be copied to the document.

If you want to *unlink* the template (with the macros) from the document you can attach the Normal template to the document (`ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate = NormalTemplate`).

When you use `SaveAs` be sure to also specify the *file format* using the `FileFormat` parameter, not just the file name. For a docx file that would be ^wdFormatXMLDocument`.

Do *not* use `ThisDocument.SaveAs` as `ThisDocument` refers to the document containing the macro. Instead, use `ActiveDocument` if you cannot otherwise use a specific `Document` object.

Answer (score 0):

It's also helpful if you specify the file format should there be any possibility that the save format isn't the same as that of the file that was opened. Hence:

```
Dim strText As String, strFilename As String
With ActiveDocument
  strText = .SelectContentControlsByTitle("STATE")(1).Range.Text
  strFilename = "C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\Quote - " & strText & ".docx"
  .SaveAs2 FileName:=strFilename, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument
End With
```