# Save a macro-enabled Word document, new file won't open

Tags: vba, ms-word

I can create a new Word document and save it as .docx:

```
Dim newDoc As Word.Document
Set newDoc = Application.Documents.Add()
' copy content etc. and then
Call newDoc.SaveAs2(filename)
```

Here filename needs not include the extension. It saves a .docx document and it works fine!

But if I want to save it as a macro-enabled Word document, the first puzzle is that I cannot find the format among those listed in `WdSaveFormat`:

```
Call newDoc.SaveAs2(filename, WdSaveFormat. ??? )
```

So I just add an extension to filename (say I call it "New Document.docm").

Now the problem is that **this new file will not open**. It seems to get stuck trying.

If I try specifying a save format

```
Call newDoc.SaveAs2(filename, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument)
```

it will throw a 6294 error.

This doesn't happen when the save format is `wdFormatDocumentDefault`. But then again it won't open.

So which save format should I choose or why will new .docm documents not open?

Comment: Why are you trying to save a macro-enabled document? This will make your document less likely to be used by others. For your own use, macros in your template will remain available in the document. Likewise, if you share your macro-enabled template and others use it enabled, they will have access to macros in the template even though using a .docx document. See http://shaunakelly.com/word/templates/templaterelations.html.

Comment: @Charles I was just going to ask precisely that, as I've seen that my macros also run in a .docx document. Thanks for the link and for another useful tip!

Comment: You are welcome. The other part of this is if you create a macro-enabled document from a macro-enabled template, that document will no more *(or less)* have the macros from your template than would a .docx. The macros in the attached template are available in the document so long as the document remains attached to the template.

Comment: @Charles I see... So any document based on a template has access to its template's modules and classes. Moreover, if you save your template in the startup folder, all documents will be able to run its macros. I thought macro-enabled meant enabled to be affected by macros, but it actually means enabled to hold macros and become a "project" on its own, which is completely unnecessary in my case.

Comment: You have it correct. Here is my writing on Global templates: https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Global and the Startup Folder in Word https://addbalance.com/word/startup.htm.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry fellow coders. It wasn't until I posted this question that I saw this related question: [Microsoft Word Save As Macro Returning Corrupt File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52595928/microsoft-word-save-as-macro-returning-corrupt-file)

To save a macro-enabled Word document I just needed to specify `WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled`:

```
Dim newDoc As Word.Document
Set newDoc = Application.Documents.Add()
' copy content etc. and then
Call newDoc.SaveAs2(filename, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled)
```

I just didn't realize Word is XML, I thought it was unrelated.